How to get surface topology from fringe pattern
I'm trying to recover the surface shape of a body from fringe pattern. There's a interferometer projecting circular fringes on the body. A camera takes a picture of the reflection of these fringes. I studied some papers doing this with unwrapping the phase of the fringen pattern. Unfortunately they don't go very deep, so I didn't get the link between the unwrapped phase and the resulting topology.
First I created a test pattern function:
def create_pattern_rings(dim, count_rings):

pattern = np.zeros((dim[0], dim[1]))
pix_per_ring = int((dim[1] / 2) / count_rings)
for ring in range(0, count_rings):
    radii_out = (dim[1] / 2) - ring*pix_per_ring*2
    radii_in = radii_out - pix_per_ring
    for y in range(0, dim[0]):
        for x in range(0, dim[1]):
            if (np.sqrt((x-dim[1]/2)**2 + (y-dim[1]/2)**2)) < radii_out and (np.sqrt((x-dim[1]/2)**2 + (y-dim[1]/2)**2)) > radii_in:
                pattern[y][x] = 1

With this pattern I do 2D fft to get the phase with numpy.angle(). This phase can be unwrapped using numpy.unwrap():
def calc_fft(data, shift):
data_fft = np.fft.fft2(data)

if shift:
    data_fft = np.fft.fftshift(data_fft)

return data_fft

def phase_unwrap(data_fft):
data_unwraped = np.unwrap(np.angle(data_fft))

return data_unwraped

But I don't know how to go one after this step. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Hi, in python code, indentation is relevant to what the program does. Sadly, it seems when pasting your code into the question, you removed at least one level of indentation. Could you fix that?
